# Jenkins .NET build failing with MSBuild 14, .NET framework 3.5 and Microsoft SDK 12 - no visual studio installed in build machine

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Jenkins .NET build failing with MSBuild 14, .NET framework 3.5 and Microsoft SDK 12 - no visual studio installed in build machine

Error log:

`````
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 12/23/2019 2:50:42 PM.
Project "D:\jenkins\slaves\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxx\xxx\***.sln" on node 1 (clean;Rebuild target(s)).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Win32".
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
Studio 2008.  [D:\jenkins\slaves\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxx\xxx\***.sln]
Done Building Project "D:\jenkins\slaves\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxx\xxx\***.sln" (clean;Rebuild target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"D:\jenkins\slaves\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxx\xxx\***.sln"
(clean;Rebuild target) (1) ->
(LoadMadeira:Clean target) ->
  MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe
".`enter code here` If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows S
DK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visu
al Studio 2008.````

tried updating the sdkpath to resolv the above error from Jenkins/local, but still no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.
`````

Comment: If updated with sdkpath the above error getting resolved in Jenkins and throwing another error.                                                                                                        12:15:08 MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
12:15:08 Switch: (x86)\Microsoft
12:15:08 
12:15:08 For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"

Comment: Even if you install only the free Microsoft Build Tools, you have to select the componetens you wish to install. Just call open the Installer once again an select the C++ components.

Comment: Hi @Holleoman, Let me try the suggestion from you and update. Thanks for your help.